# How do I turn a person who is trying to scam me to the authorities?

Tags: scams, money-laundering

I'm looking for a contact or website to turn in a person I believe is part of a huge scam. He's offering 5.5 million dollars :-) It might be money laundering.

Comment: Which authorities? What jurisdiction? Regardless, the answer would be to contact the appropriate authorities and tell them everything you know about the scam

Comment: At $5.5M, it's more likely to be an advance fee fraud, rather than money laundering.

Comment: Well, I don't think those princes/tycoons want you to launder their money for them. 
 Go check out : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance-fee_scam

Comment: What country and locality are you in?

Comment: I am in Idaho, USA. I have filed a complaint with the FBI here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you suspect the scammer is operating across state lines, on the internet and/or internationally your best bet is likely to report it to the FBI.

[FBI Internet Crime Complaint Center](https://www.ic3.gov/default.aspx)

Also, check out the [FBI Scams and Safety page](https://www.fbi.gov/scams-and-safety).

Answer (score 0):

The US government maintains a [website](https://www.usa.gov/stop-scams-frauds) meant as a portal for all topics related to scams. It has a [listing of reporting mechanisms.](https://www.usa.gov/stop-scams-frauds#item-35157) It's a good resource, since you can read through the reporting section and decide which authorities you should report a specific scam to.

Separately from that, if the scammer has suggested or attempted using any specific company or entity as part of the scam, you should do your best to report the scam attempt to that entity. For instance, if they suggested you open an account at a specific bank or credit union, let that institution know of the attempt. Or, if they suggested you make payments via a specific payment network (i.e. PayPal), or they wrere using Craigslist or eBay or some other website as part of the scam, you should inform those entities. Many times, scams are designed based on what a scammer knows about loopholes or exploits in a specific bank or website; informing the entity they targeted of the scam attempt can help them close those loopholes and/or investigate the attempt as necessary. This can help shut that particular scam model down, which makes things safer for future victims.